# Mudar a linha das legendas Google Charts

Tags: javascript, api, google, highcharts, google-charts

Atualmente estou usando a API do Google (Google Charts) para gerar alguns gráficos, Porém notei que quando há porcentagens pequenas, ex: 0.94%, 1.2%, ele torna a leitura dos "labels" um pouco confusa, "uma em cima da outra".
É possível mudar a linha  "Path" do gráfico? Para que fique parecido com a do Highcharts:

[image: Gráfico gerado pelo Google Charts]

[image: Gráfico gerado pelo Highcharts]

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem o que você quer. Para exibir valores pequenos no gráfico de pizza utilize: `sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0`, nas `options`.

**Exemplo:**

```
var options = {
   fontSize: 11,
   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
   width: "100%",
   sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
   legend: { textStyle: { fontSize: 12 } },
   pieHole: 0.60,
   height: 400,
};
```